# ScrollViewer Content StackPanel выдаёт исключение

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как исправить исключение Specified element is already the logical child of another element?

myScrollViewer.Content = spi;

Answer (score 1):

Добавить блок **[finaly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)**, что ты в любом случае запустилось. Хотя могу нести бред т.к. автор не предоставил код и не описал проблему.